# Can we remove the textarea border for asking/posting questions?

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, unregistered-users

This is a bug report/feature-request.

***The feature-request:***

Normally, the border is fine, but for unregistered users, or registered users who click the 'help' button, the top part of the border disappears, and it ends up looking really bad:

Normally: (looks fine)
[image]
With help bar: (looks bad)
[image]

Can you [add `outline:0px !important` and `-webkit-appearance:none` to the `textarea`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8622740/3541881)!

***The bug*** - if the feature request sounds bad (if it is a bug):

The help bar covers the top-border of the textarea, can the bar be moved up please?